# Django template tag comparison not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to compare two values in a Django template tag, but it's not working like I expect it to. Here's what my template markup looks like:

```
<ul>
{% for c in category %}
{% ifequal c.name|stringformat:"%s" values.project_category|stringformat:"%s" %}
<li>Values equal ({{c.name}}:{{values.project_category}})</li>
{% else %}
<li>Values differ ({{c.name}}:{{values.project_category}})</li>
{% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The `values` item is a dictionary that gets passed to the template from the view, while the `category` is a QuerySet that I iterate over. The `values` dictionary starts out empty, but I get this output:

```
Values equal (One:)
Values equal (Two:)
Values equal (Three:)
```

As you can see from the output, the values do not equal (the `values` items don't show up because they don't exist). What am I doing wrong here? I assumed it must have been a typing issue, which is why I chose to use the `stringformat` modifier, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is using "%s" in the stringformat filter. Leading % are dropped by the filter:

[Django stringformat filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat)

Thus, you are just converting both strings to the literal "%s", and since "%s" == "%s" your ifequal is always true.